# Why is SDL2 rectangle and line drawing not pixel perfect?

Tags: c++, windows, sdl-2, dpi, renderer

When using SDL2 (2.0.8), drawing a 2D rectangle or a line with SDL_RenderDrawRect or SDL_RenderDrawLine is not pixel perfect. There are some artifacts. Why is that? And is there a way to prevent that?

[image: SDL2 rectangle and line drawing]

Code example:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include "SDL.h"
#else
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#endif

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window*   window = SDL_CreateWindow("test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1000, 800, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, 0,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
    SDL_Event event;
    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
            {
                quit = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 40, 10, 60, 10);
        SDL_Rect rect{10, 10, 20, 20};
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &rect);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Environment:
Acer Laptop, Intel HD Graphics, NVIDIA GEFORCE 940m, Windows 10

Comment: You should provide code that you use for rendering. And yet how do you initialize window and scaling on it.

Comment: Pixel perfect on my machine.

Comment: Thank you for adding your MCVE code.  I cut-n-paste, compiled, and ran it on my machine... still pixel perfect.  Did Scott Mudge's answer work?  Maybe the defaults on my machine differ from the defaults on your machine.

Comment: Yes it was a machine setting, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Windows 10 display settings "Scale and Layout" was set to "125%". After Setting it to "100%" the rendering was pixel perfect.

[Windows 10 display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBGjp.png)

Though this is just a workaraound. The real solution is to call the Windows API function "SetProcessDpiAwareness". I found the answer and code to do that on different Windows versions in this link:

[SetProcessDpiAwareness](https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/sdl-getdesktopdisplaymode-resolution-reported-in-windows-10-when-using-app-scaling/22389/4)

There are different methods to set the DPI awareness depending on the Windows OS version. It can be set programmatically or by Application Manifest. See the

[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process).

Setting "Scale and Layout" back to "125%" and calling that function at the begin of my application gives the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

[this dude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52028160/14107105) is right. But `SetProcessDpiAwareness` is undefined in my case.
`SetProcessDPIAware()` work for me.

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif

int main(int, char**)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    SetProcessDPIAware();// Fix DPI settings
#endif
    //some code
}
```

I hope this code helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "couldn't find"? Is SetProcessDpiAwareness not in the sdk you are using? The example from https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/sdl-getdesktopdisplaymode-resolution-reported-in-windows-10-when-using-app-scaling/22389/4 is more Windows version agnostic (and uses more SDL functionality).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY

Make sure to disable this and set it to 0. You may also wish to ensure anti-aliasting is disabled in your video drivers/NVIDIA Control Panel.

There are many upstream factors that may cause this.

Comment: Indeed this is machine dependend. The picture i posted is from an Acer Laptop with Intel HD Graphics and NVIDIA GEFORCE 940M card. Today I tried the code on an Raspberry Pi 3 with software and experimental openGL renderer, both were fine, except with the experimental openGL driver the rectangle was missing a pixel in the top left corner. Lastly i ran the code on my main PC with an NVIDIA GTX 980, also no problems.

Comment: Changing the rendering hints in code made no difference.